# @ApplicationScope in Spring Boot Application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, global-variables

Is this correct Implementation

```
@ApplicationScope
@Component
public class OnlineModeStatus {

boolean online;

public boolean isOnline() {
    return online;
}

public void setOnline(boolean status) {
    this.online= status;
}

}
```

I need to have a global variable to maintain the status of the application to Cloud Service
if the Cloud Service is down/not reachable then the global variable will be false

so depending upon the variable I need to take action

Is this the right implementation ?

Answer (score 0):

Your Code is fine. I don't see a problem with your Code.

**But if you want some improvements here, you go:**

1. Use `private` access modifier for the online field
2. Use volatile keyword for the online field: This makes your code more thread-safe.
3. Use an `enum` instead of a `boolean` for the online field:  This can make the code clearer and more flexible, as you can define specific states such as ONLINE, OFFLINE, CONNECTING, and so on.

```java
    @ApplicationScope
    @Component
    public class OnlineModeStatus {
    
        private volatile OnlineStatus onlineStatus = OnlineStatus.ONLINE;
    
        public OnlineStatus getOnlineStatus() {
            return onlineStatus;
        }
    
        public void setOnlineStatus(OnlineStatus onlineStatus) {
            this.onlineStatus = onlineStatus;
        }
    
        public boolean isOnline() {
            return onlineStatus == OnlineStatus.ONLINE;
        }
    
        public enum OnlineStatus {
            ONLINE,
            OFFLINE,
            CONNECTING
        }
    }
```